# Is there a keyboard shortcut to move the position of a tab in Safari?

Tags: safari

How do you move a tab's position amongst other tabs using the keyboard? Is it possible?

Comment: I know of no method other than dragging it.

Comment: I updated my answer, so you might want to review it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be a built-in keyboard shortcut to change the position of a given tab amongst other tabs in Safari.  At least none listed in the Apple Support Documents listed below.

- [Safari 6/7 (Mavericks): Safari shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17148?locale=en_US)
- [Safari 8 (Yosemite): Safari keyboard and other shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19282?locale=en_US)
- [Safari 9 (El Capitan): Safari keyboard and other shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21483?locale=en_US)

One might be able to create an Automator Service with a Run Apple Script Action to manipulate tabs in a Safari windows and then assign it a keyboard shortcut in Keyboard System Preferences, however I'd imagine it might not be to easy to code.

**Update:**

I looked through the Safari AppleScript Dictionary and played around with the coding of an AppleScript script to manipulated tab ordering, or I should say the appearance of tab ordering, as even a simple command such as `move last tab to before first tab` required a refresh of the URL. In other words whether or not I coded it via `move` or switching the URL of the current and next tab, etc, all methods I tried forces/requires a refresh of the URL, where dragging and dropping a tab only changes the tab order and does not refresh any tab when done in a DnD manner.

In conclusion, if you don't mind the tab URL being refreshed then the appearance of drag and drop can be accomplished however to physically move a tab without it refreshing would probably require the use of third-party utilities and much more complex coding then coding using `move` or swapping the URLs of adjacent tabs, etc.

Comment: Is this still true for Safari 10?